# How to extract a skype account using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract a skype accounts from the array of strings.
They appear after word "skype: " in the string. So I need the way to extract them using regex.
And it looks like I need something like: string RegexPattern = @"skype:\s*(\w*)";
But when this regex meets the account with . (dot) like P.Revenko.Sokolniki it returns only first letter (P in this case), and it has to be P.Revenko.Sokolniki.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why cant you just remove the first 6 characters from the string?

Comment: skype: P.Revenko.Sokolniki ; skype:P.Revenko.Sokolniki ; skype: PRevenko.Sokolniki ; skype:PRevenkoSokolniki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited:** use this:

```
skype:\s*(?<account>[\w.]*)
```

and get group named *account* like this:

```
String skypeAccount = Regex.Match(inputString, @"skype:\s*(?<account>(\w|\.)*)").Groups["account"].Value;
```

Comment: This string RegexPattern = @"skype:\s*(\w\.)*"; returns the first char and dot like P.

Comment: Instead of `(\w|\.)` you could also just use `[\w.]`.

Answer (score 2):

If they're all delimited by a semi-colon, there's no need for regular expressions.

However, a solution using Regex would be the following:

```
string pattern = "(?<=skype:\s*)(?<account>[^\s]+)";
```

#### Explanation

```
(?<=skype:\s*)    --look behind for an instance of "skype:" followed by any number of spaces
(?<account>       --named capture group called "account
    [^\s]+        --match any character that is not a space, and do it at least once.
)                 --group closure
```

However, as I said earlier there really isn't a need for RegEx, you can simply use a smattering of string manipulation.

```
string rawSkype = "skype: example1 ; skype: example2.com";
string[] skypeNames = Array.ConvertAll(rawSkype.Split(';'), 
                                       raw => raw.Replace("skype:", "").Trim());
```

And that works just as easily.

Comment: `\S` would be shorthand for `[^\s]`.

Comment: @Joey yes, but it's less intuitive when explaining to someone.
Roman, then the RegEx should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put \w\. into square brackets

```
string c = "skype: P.Jon.Doe";

Regex ex = new Regex(@"^skype:\s*[\w\.]*");

if (ex.IsMatch(c))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Match(c).Value);
}
```